# MSForms.ReturnInteger - Changing shape's position using vbKey

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub Test(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer) 
If (KeyCode = vbKeyUp) Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("X").IncrementTop -10
End If
```

I found this code snippet in an old forum, I tried replicating the results but to no luck. What is the error?

Comment: "I tried replicating the results but to no luck" - "no luck" looked like what exactly - what happened which was different from what you expected?

Comment: I was expecting the shape to move up by 10 units. The shape didn't move at all.

Comment: Where did you put that, and how did you call it?  It looks like it should be an event handler, but the name doesn't look right.  the method signature should be something more like `Private Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)`

Comment: Oh god. Thanks a lot! I completely forgot about that also, is it possible to run a sub-routine via arrow keys without calling it? Is there any other method?

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't have customizable keyboard shortcuts, though there are add-ins that make this possible. You can also use events to run macros, here's a list: http://www.officeoneonline.com/vba/events_version.html